# Unable to upload file(ng-file upload) in firefox browser with protractor?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firefox, protractor, ng-file-upload

I am working on test automation of an angular app using protractor+jasmine, and we used ng-file uploader for upload files in our app. The automation script successfully uploads file in Chrome browser but not working in firefox browser and I am getting the following error :

Message:
    Failed: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with

Stack:
    ElementNotVisibleError: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with

## Code snippet for file upload

```
this.uploadFile = function (uploadFile) {
    var fileToUpload = uploadFile;
    var absolutePath = path.resolve(__dirname, fileToUpload);
    $('input[type="file"]').sendKeys(absolutePath);
    element(submitBtn).click();
};

<label style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute; overflow: hidden; width: 0px; height: 0px; border: medium none; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;" tabindex="-1">
upload
<input id="ngf-{{ id }}" type="file" ngf-change="onChange($file)" ngf-keep="{{ keep }}" required="required" ngf-validate="{{ validate }}" ngf-pattern="{{ pattern }}" ngf-accept="{{ allowedMime }}" ngf-multiple="{{ multipleAllowed }}" ngf-model-invalid="invalid" ng-model-options="{ allowInvalid: multipleAllowed }" ng-model="files" ngf-select="" ngf-drop="" name="{{ name }}" accept=".csv,text/plain,application/vnd.ms-excel"/>
```

**Any help would be greatly appreciated!!**

Comment: per my experience "Element is not currently visible" error suggests that element that you are trying to interact with is not displayed in current view. Could be resolution issue too. Can you confirm if the element is actually in view while you interact with it?

Comment: element is hidden.

Comment: Which Firefox driver are you using and is it a local or remote session?

Comment: Local. Firefox version 45.3.0(ESR version)

Answer (score 0):

Woohoo..!! Finally I fixed the issue and able to upload file in firefox browser.

Please see the code :

```
this.uploadFile = function (uploadFile) {
    if(browser.browserName === 'firefox') {
        browser.executeAsyncScript(function(callback) {
            document.querySelectorAll('body>label')[0].setAttribute('style', 'position: absolute');
            callback();
        });
    }
    var fileToUpload = uploadFile;
    var absolutePath = path.resolve(__dirname, fileToUpload);
    $('input[type="file"]').sendKeys(absolutePath);
    element(uploadBtn).click();
};
```

And for getting the browser name, please add the following in your conf.js file

```
onPrepare: function () {
    browser.driver.getCapabilities().then(function(caps){
        browser.browserName = caps.get('browserName');
    });
}
```

Also note that document.querySelectorAll('body>label')[0].setAttribute('style', 'position: absolute'); will remove all attribute in my hidden label tag making my input tag(child of label tag) visible and set position to absolute.

So then firefox won't throw the error : Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with